Migrating aws aurora rds db from serverless v1 to serverless v2 using terraform
I've been tasked with upgrading our AWS Aurora engine from Serverless version 1 to Serverless version 2 using Terraform. The steps described are basically to take a snapshot, create a new Provisioned Aurora cluster (not Serverless) and then upgrade the Provisioned Cluster to Postgres 13.6 and after that Clone the new 13.6 Cluster into a Serverless v2.
However, I get stuck with the error: RDS Cluster FinalSnapshotIdentifier is required when a final snapshot is required
I'm providing the snapshot identifier attribute, I've no idea what is going wrong with my code.
Creating old v1 cluster
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
  cluster_identifier              = local.env_config.rds_db_identifier
  engine                          = local.env_config.rds_engine
  engine_mode                     = local.env_config.rds_engine_mode
  engine_version                  = local.env_config.rds_engine_version
  allow_major_version_upgrade     = local.env_config.rds_allow_major_version_upgrade
  apply_immediately               = local.env_config.rds_apply_immediately

  master_username = local.env_config.auroradb_user
  master_password = random_password.aurora_passwd.result
  # final_snapshot_identifier = "aurora-cluster-snapshot-7654"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.aurora.id]
  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.aurora_group.id

  copy_tags_to_snapshot        = true
  deletion_protection          = false
  enable_http_endpoint         = true
  preferred_maintenance_window = local.env_config.preferred_maintenance_window
  backup_retention_period      = 14
  preferred_backup_window      = "01:00-02:00"
  skip_final_snapshot          = false
  final_snapshot_identifier = "aurora-cluster-snapshot-7654"
  storage_encrypted            = true
}

Creating snapshot
resource "aws_db_cluster_snapshot" "aurora_snapshot" {
  db_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.aurora.id
  db_cluster_snapshot_identifier = "aurora-cluster-snapshot"
  tags = local.default_tags
}

Creating provisioned db from snapshot
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_pg_v2" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-cluster-new-provisioned-v29067"
  engine  = local.env_config.rds_engine
  engine_version  = local.env_config.rds_engine_version
  database_name = local.env_config.auroradb_name
  master_username = local.env_config.auroradb_user
  master_password = random_password.aurora_passwd.result
  snapshot_identifier = aws_db_cluster_snapshot.aurora_snapshot.id
  backup_retention_period = 14
  preferred_backup_window = "01:00-02:00"
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.aurora_group.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.aurora.id]
  engine_mode = "provisioned"
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  apply_immediately = true

  depends_on = [aws_db_cluster_snapshot.aurora_snapshot]
}

Creating db instances
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_pg_v2_instance" {
  count = 2 # Example: Two instances (one writer, one reader)
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.aurora_pg_v2.id
  instance_class = "db.r5.large"
  engine = local.env_config.rds_engine
  engine_version  = local.env_config.rds_engine_version
  publicly_accessible  = false
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.aurora_group.id
  apply_immediately = true
}

Creating serverless db
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_pg_v2_serverless" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-pg-v2-serverless-cluster-new-197789"
  engine = local.env_config.rds_engine
  engine_version = local.env_config.rds_engine_version
  database_name = local.env_config.auroradb_name
  master_username = local.env_config.auroradb_user
  master_password = random_password.aurora_passwd.result
  backup_retention_period = 14
  preferred_backup_window = "01:00-02:00"
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.aurora_group.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.aurora.id]
  engine_mode = "serverless"
  apply_immediately = true
  enable_http_endpoint         = true
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.fhirdevplatform_rds_log]
  timeouts {
    create = "120m"
  }
  scaling_configuration {
    auto_pause = true
    min_capacity = 2
    max_capacity = 4
  }
}

I tried writing the terraform code to migrate the db and it's working fine but I'm stuck with one particular error

In your resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_pg_v2_serverless" resource, you haven't specified anything for skip_final_snapshot, so that value is defaulting to false. When that value is false, a final_snapshot_identifier value is required. You have not specified that value for that resource either.
So you either need to add skip_final_snapshot = true to that resource, or you need to add a final_snapshot_identifier value.

we usually add that tag if the cluster is getting destroyed or deleted right? In my case "aurora_pg_v2_serverless" gets created but never deleted. Am I missing something here?

No, you have to have that attribute all the time, or set skip_final_snapshot = true. Terraform requires you to tell it at creation time what to do with the resource if it ever is destroyed. That's because the terraform destroy command uses the settings from the current state file, so by the time you run terraform destroy it is too late to set or change those values.
